# If $\mu$ is $f$-invariant for a collection generating the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, then $\mu$ is $f$-invariant?

Tags: measure-theory, ergodic-theory

Let $\left(M,\sigma\left(\tau\right)\right)$ a measure space with
$\sigma\left(\tau\right)$ a Borel $\sigma$-algebra where $\tau$
is a topology in $M$. Suppose there is  a collection $\mathcal{B}$ of elements in collection $\mathcal{B}$ in  $\sigma\left(\tau\right)$ such that  $\sigma\left(\tau\right)$ is generated by $\mathcal{B}$  and $\mu\left(B\right)=\mu\left(f^{-1}\left(B\right)\right)$ for all $B\in\mathcal{B}$, then $\mu\left(E\right)=\mu\left(f^{-1}\left(E\right)\right)$ for all $E\in\sigma\left(\tau\right)$.

**Remark:** If $\mathcal{B}$ is an algebra, then the proof is easy, it can be found in the book Ergodic Theory of Ricardo Mañé. The question is that $\mathcal{B}$ is not necessarily an algebra, then I thought about looking for an algebra $\mathcal{C}$ contaning $\mathcal{B}$  such that $\mu\left(C\right)=\mu\left(f^{-1}\left(C\right)\right)$ for all $C\in\mathcal{C}$. Precisely, I thought the candidate for that algebra was

$\mathcal{C}=\left\{C\in \sigma\left(\tau\right) : \mu\left(C\right)=\mu\left(f^{-1}\left(C\right)\right) \right\} $

but I could not prove that $\mathcal{C}$ is an algebra. I'm thinking that's not true, but i can not find a counterexample. Really, I'm thinking that in the main question we need more conditions on the collection $\mathcal{B}$, but i can not find a counterexample.

Comment: I guess this is general, but if $\mu$ is a finite measure you can play with the fact that $f^{-1}$ behaves very well under sets operations. From that you can have that $\mathcal{C}$ is in fact an algebra. Maybe there is a way to avoid the sets with infinity measure...

Comment: I forget to say in the statement that the measure is finite, in the infinite case I found a counterexample. The problem in $\mathcal{C}$  is show that the union of any two elements in $\mathcal{C}$ are in $\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: The family $\mathcal{C}$ is clearly a $\lambda$-system. You could try the $\pi - \lambda$-theorem.

Comment: Try to define $\mathcal{C}_{\epsilon} = \{ C : \| \mu(A) - \mu (f^{-1}(A)) \| < \epsilon\}$

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, considering his comments, if we added the condition that $\mathcal{B}$ is closed under intersections of any two elements, then  the statement is proved. Now, the problem is to find an example in which $\mathcal{B}$ is not closed under intersections and the statement is not true.